# Calculating bond energy per molecule

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry, solid-mechanics

I'm currently going through a book on material science, a field of which I have little background knowledge. One of the questions asks me to calculate the *bond energy per molecule* when given the following data

- Bond energy: 7.74 kJ $\text{mol}^{-1}$
- Density: 1.77 g $\text{cm}^{-3}$
- Relative atomic mass: 40 g $\text{mol}^{-1}$

I'm completely stuck. The bond energy per molecule is supposed to be compared to specified bond lengths (from $1\times 10^{-20}$ to $100 \times 10^{-20}$) to identify the type of bond, but every method I've come up with has given me answers that aren't comparable to those bond lenghts. Am I missing a fundamental definition here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given a value of Bond energy per unit mole. To find bond energy per molecule, We need to find out How many molecules are in 1 mole.

We know that it's equal to the Avogadro number. Putting this on bond energy per unit mole,
$$7.74\frac{\textrm{kJ}}{\textrm{mol}}=7.74\times N_A\frac{\textrm{kJ}}{\textrm{molecule}}=51.3\times 10^{23} \ \textrm{kJ / molecule}$$

Comment: You don't think that's a little large? The bond energies are supposed to be on order of thermal energies, which is at room temperature around $10^{-20} \text{ to } 100\times10^{-20}$. I've already tried dividing the given bond energy by Avagadro's number, but this method seems to break down when dealing with larger bond energies...

Answer (score 0):

Upon closer inspection of my textbook, the range $10^{-20} \text{ to } 100\times10^{-20}$ isn't a hard range of values required for the answer. They just have be on the *order* of this range!

Bond energies can be larger and still fit the classification.

Here is a reminder to *read the textbook* before posting desperate questions on StackExchange. :D